# Is a Noble Lie Possible?

Tags: ethics

Plato describes a noble lie in Republic as a falsehood which should be perpetuated for a greater good.

I am thinking of a marksman that leads his moving target such that his shot is accurate.  The marksman is not lying to himself, he knows that he must aim ahead in order for the shot to hit his target.

What does reliance on a lie say about a group?  Looking at my USA passport I see proclamation of lying (bending our world) by a Texan and an appreciation of what our world is from a Mohawk:

> For this is what America is all about.  It is the uncrossed desert and
>   the unclimbed ridge.  It is the star that is not reached and the
>   harvest sleeping in the unplowed ground.  Is our world gone?  We say
>   "Farewell." Is a new world coming? We welcome it - and we will bend it
>   to the hopes of man. -Lyndon B. Johnson
>
> We send thanks to all the Animal life in the world.  They have many
>   things to teach us as people.  We are glad they are still here and we
>   hope it will always be so. - Excerpt from the Thanksgiving Address,
>   Mohawk version
>   
>   [image]

Comment: Is there any chance you could spell out a little more clearly what exactly you would like someone here to explain to you?

Comment: Lying.  Why are we lying to ourselves?  Are we to trust in G-d?  Or, should we not trust in G-d?  Or, is G-d the noble lie?  Joseph, the subject is pretty wide open.  I am interested in what you have to say.

Comment: @Ron Royston It sounds like you want a discussion rather than an answer. The answer to the title question is obviously "yes" according to Plato, is there some specific part of his reasoning that you question, or perspective on it from some specific other school of thought that you are interested in?

Comment: There seem to be at least two not clearly identical things going on here: (1) whether a noble lie is possible  and (2) whether it is a problem to depend on something that isn't true on either the level of performing an individual skill or as a society. Then there's a picture of part of your passport with two quotes.

Comment: I don't understand... you're saying LBJ's quote is a lie? It seems to be more of an opinion than a lie.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery "We will bend [our new world] to the hopes of man."  Bend the truth.  A noble lie.

Answer (score 3):

Plato's concept of the *Noble Lie* needs to be understood in context --it isn't fully captured by the gloss of a falsehood in service of a greater good.

In Plato's view, our entire world is an illusion.  Everything we typically think of as truth is a lie.  The *Noble Lie* is a lie because it doesn't correspond with the facts as we typically understand them.  But it is *noble* because it corresponds with a deeper Truth in a deeper Reality.

You can't truly have a *noble lie* in the proper Platonic sense unless you don't believe the facts are definitive of Truth.

Comment: Platonic realism isn't fully captured by the gloss of everything we typically think of as truth is a lie.  The cave allegory fits here so a a higher truth/reality fits, not a deeper truth/reality.  Lie connotes intentional deception.  Falsehood is better.

Answer (score -1):

ψεῦδος, actually translates to "false."  The connotation of deception introduced by the translation of ψεῦδος to "lie" appears to be the source of confusion.  A noble falsehood is more palatable insofar as the originator of the falsehood is ignorant of the degree of falseness, or at what point the allegory breaks down when subjected to reality/nature.

It seems as long as we depend on falsehoods for motivation or direction, we can safely be characterized as a mislead people.

We are presented with the cave allegory.  We also know of the fundamental concept of ownership in Western thought vs the leave it as your found it thought of the natives.